# Navigation Drawer Template in Android Studio doesn't show any design in the xml files

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

[image: Screenshot from Android studio content_main.xml]

I used the Android NavDrawer template, but it doesn't want to show the design in the layout just like in the screenshot I sent, with a message "Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme".

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)